# How to find out which application opened a handle to physical drive on Windows?

Tags: windows, partitioning, file-management

I want to find out which application are using System Reserved Partition.
As I understand, Process Explorer and Handle from sysinternals can only find such applications for specific file, but I want to do it for partition which doesn't have even a letter.

I need something like

```
lsof /dev/sdb1
```

But for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Reserved Partition isn't really a physical drive. It's a logical drive. Try SysInternal's "[Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx)" utility with `handle.exe -a \Device\Harddisk`

Here is the output on my PC:

```
System             pid: 4      type: Directory      188: \Device\Harddisk0
System             pid: 4      type: File           1E0: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Boot\BCD
System             pid: 4      type: File           1E8: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Boot\BCD.LOG
System             pid: 4      type: File           63C: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
System             pid: 4      type: File           6D4: \Device\HarddiskVolume2?☺
System             pid: 4      type: File           71C: \Device\HarddiskVolume2?☺
System             pid: 4      type: File          12B4: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog\$TxfLog.blf

System             pid: 4      type: File          1398: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog\$TxfLogCont
ainer00000000000000000002
System             pid: 4      type: File          1530: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$Txf
System             pid: 4      type: File          1600: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\$Extend\$RmMetadata\$TxfLog\$TxfLogCont
ainer00000000000000000001
svchost.exe        pid: 704    type: File           678: \Device\Harddisk0\DR0
svchost.exe        pid: 996    type: File           7B4: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
svchost.exe        pid: 76     type: File           558: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
MsMpEng.exe        pid: 3064   type: File           1A0: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
MsMpEng.exe        pid: 3064   type: File           DB0: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
explorer.exe       pid: 3396   type: File           7EC: \Device\Harddisk0\DR0
SearchIndexer.exe  pid: 5628   type: File           900: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
```

As you see there are handles to \Device\Harddisk0\ which are handles to physical drives, logical drives, and specific files.